# how to override checkable.phtml in custom module

Tags: magento2, magento2.4

I just want to override `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/base/templates/product/composite/fieldset/options/view/checkable.php` in my custom module but I can't

I can't find any solution to this

already tried using template hierarchy but not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your custom module etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select\Checkable" type="VendorName\ModuleName\Rewrite\Checkable"/>
</config>
```

In VendorName/ModuleName/Rewrite/Checkable.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright ©  All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace VendorName\ModuleName\Rewrite;

class Checkable extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select\Checkable
{
    protected $_template = 'VendorName_ModuleName::product/composite/fieldset/options/view/checkable.phtml';
}
```

Comment: tried the same way but getting this error :
Uncaught Error: Class 'Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select\Magento\Product\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select/Checkable.php:15

Comment: Please check the paths and make sure the paths are correct. I find issue is with the paths.

Answer (score 0):

The above file is set from this block file.

> Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select\Checkable.php

So you need to overide this file into custom module and then need to set the template file instade of orignal one.

Comment: i tried but got this error after compile:
Uncaught Error: Class 'Vendor\Module\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select\Magento\Product\Block\Product\View\Options\Type\Select' not found in /var/www/html/app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/Product/View/Options/Type/Select/Checkable.php:15

Comment: please ask the seprate question for this one with the code, sop you will get the answer of that one like how to overide the block.